# I want to create a Java source that functions like TO_NUMBER of Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

For example...
Apply the hexadecimal "DE82C38142C69491" to Oracle TO_NUMBER
The results are as follows.

```
select TO_NUMBER('DE82C38142C69491', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') from dual

/* 
result : 
16033592583330894993 
*/
```

I tried this in Java and the code is as below.

```
Long.parseUnsignedLong("DE82C38142C69491", 16);

/*
result : 
-2413151490378656623
*/
```

I'm understanding something wrong.
Is there a way to use Oracle's TO_NUMBER in Java?

Answer (score 2):

The hexadecimal number DE82C38142C69491 is -2413151490378656623.

Java longs are signed, and D has the top bit set, so DE82C38142C69491 represents a negative number.

Run `System.out.println(Long.toHexString(-2413151490378656623L));` and you'll see you get `DE82C38142C69491` back.

So you have all the bits of your original hex number.

You can use `new BigInteger("DE82C38142C69491", 16);` which will get you a BigInteger containing 16033592583330894993, but -2413151490378656623 already contains all your bits.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `long` is a signed 64-bit integer type supporting values in the range of -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

In Java 8 however, some methods were added to the type `long` for *unsigned handling*, for example [`Long.compareUnsigned(long x, long y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-). While the older methods will continue to consider `long` values as signed, these new ones work with a range of 0 to 2<sup>64</sup>-1. [The documentation states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an
> unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum
> value of 2<sup>64</sup>-1.

It's just a different interpretation. For that reason...

```
System.out.println(Long.parseUnsignedLong("DE82C38142C69491", 16));
```

...which is effectively calling `Long.toString()`, will output:

```
-2413151490378656623
```

But if you do...

```
System.out.println(Long.toUnsignedString(Long.parseUnsignedLong("DE82C38142C69491", 16)));
```

...you will get:

```
16033592583330894993
```

That's because `16033592583330894993` is bigger than 2<sup>63</sup>-1 but also smaller than 2<sup>64</sup>-1.

Still, if you're dealing with numbers that big, you're probably better off using [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html).